# Evaluating $\left.\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1+\frac1{\sqrt{1+\tan^nx}}}\text dx \middle/\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-\frac1{\sqrt{1+\tan^nx}}}\text dx\right.$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, ratio, trigonometric-integrals

> Evaluate the integral ratio$$\dfrac{I_1}{I_2}=\dfrac{\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^nx}}} \mathrm{d}x}{\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^nx}}} \mathrm{d}x}$$

Using Wolframalpha, I found out that the ratio of the above two integrals is $\sqrt{2}+1$, that is, independent of $n$. I couldn't think of a way to solve it.

I don't think any simple substitutions would work here. Any useful hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try taking the derivative with respect to $n$ and trying to show that is 0?

Comment: Well, I didn't try that...but wouldn't that be a tedious task? Initially, the question was in the form of a particular value assigned to $n$, so one wouldn't even know that it is same for all $n$ if one doesn't take the help from computer. So, I am hoping for a method that would yield the answer by computing it...

Comment: what is the source of problem?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore A friend gave it to me.

Comment: Often the change of variables $x\mapsto \frac\pi2-x$ can be helpful here ($\tan x$ changes to $\cot x$, and then algebra allows the new function to look very similar to the old function). I couldn't make it work though.

Comment: @GregMartin Ofcourse, that would be the first instinct for everyone who will see this kind of problem, but I also don't see that to be very helpful here.

Comment: I think there is some trick like first finding $\frac{I_1+I_2}{I_1-I_2}$ and then finding ratio

Comment: Looks, like the solution lies in some clever change of variables, like $\cos^2 \theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \tan^n x}}$.                                                                                    The result mentioned can be obtained in the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$. In this case $$\tan^n x = \begin{cases}0, x < \frac{\pi}{4} \\ \infty, x > \frac{\pi}{4}\end{cases}$$. So the numerator would give : $\frac{\pi}{4} (\sqrt{2} + 1)$, and the denominator $\frac{\pi}{4} $, which is desired $\sqrt{2} + 1$. However it is only limiting case.

Comment: @spiridon_the_sun_rotator, If $x > \frac{\pi}{4}$, then $\tan^n x=\infty$, so wouldn't that imply that ratio will tend to $1$?

Comment: @Vilakshan on the interval $(0, \pi / 4)$ the integrand of the upper integral is $\sqrt{2}$, and on the interval $(\pi  4, \pi / 2)$ it is $1$. For the lower integral $1$ and $0$ correspondingly.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Note

\begin{align}
\frac{I_1}{I_2}&=1+ \frac{I_1-I_2}{I_2} \\
&=1+\frac1{I_2}\int_0^{\frac\pi2} \left( \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^nx}}}-  \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^nx}}} \right)dx \\
&=1+\frac1{I_2}\int_0^{\frac\pi2}
\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sin^nx+\cos^nx}+\sqrt{\cos^nx}}
 - \sqrt{\sqrt{\sin^nx+\cos^nx}-\sqrt{\cos^nx}}}{\sqrt[4]{\sin^nx+\cos^nx}}dx \\
&=1+\frac1{I_2} \int_0^{\frac\pi2}
\frac{\sqrt{2\sqrt{\sin^nx+\cos^nx}-2\sqrt{\sin^nx}}
}{\sqrt[4]{\sin^nx+\cos^nx}}dx \\
&= 1+\frac{\sqrt2}{I_2} \int_0^{\frac\pi2} \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cot^nx}}}dx\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>(x\to \frac\pi2-x)\\
&=1+\frac{\sqrt2}{I_2}\int_0^{\frac\pi2} \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^nx}}}dx \\ &=1+\sqrt2 \\
\end{align}

Comment: could you explain how you went from 3rd to 4rth line

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore - take the square of the numerator and then the square-root of the result

Comment: got it! beatiful proof!(+1)

Comment: More generally, if $g\left(x\right)=\frac{f\left(x\right)}{f\left(a+b-x\right)}$ then $\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+g}}}dx=\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+g}}}dx$. This is the case where $f(x)=\sin^nx,\,a=0,\,b=\pi/2$.

Comment: I could not understand the last line $d(\frac {\pi}{2}-x)=-dx$. But I can not see negative sign..(I dont have experience) can you give information me?

Comment: @lonestudent - there is another negative sign from $\int_{\pi/2}^0 \to - \int_0^{\pi/2}$, which cancels the negative sign of $-dx$

Comment: I have overlooked the boundaries of integration. I understand now.  I slipped into indefinite integration